# Sharepoint _api/contextinfo fails with 401 Unauthorized using PostMan

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, postman

Im currently using Postman app to try the various Sharepoint Api.

To retrieve the RequestDigest i understand there has to be an api call to /_api/contextinfo with nothing in Body and Accept as application/json; odata=verbose in the Header. However i get 401 AUTHORIZED error as return rather than the digest value [Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c40Gz.png)

I have tried setting the Authorization to Basic in the first tab and entered the domain credentials (which has access to the site) however it still fails.

How to resolve the error

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue with Postman Desktop application.

The solution I found is to use the NTLM Authentication.

[image: NTLM Authentication in Postman]

However, I still have to figure out how to perform this from an external Java application that would reach the REST API.

Comment: Thanks, NTML Authentication works actually for sharepoint on prem deployment.